# Reference item in sub-schema of model in Mongoose ODM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, mongoose-schema

Im setting up my MongoDB models, and I have one models schema (`Partition` model) setup in such a way that one of the schema items (`fields`) is an array of items that follows another schema (`Field` schema)

Here's the Partition model (with the Partition schema and the Field schema):

```js
// Partition model
module.exports = Mongoose => {     
    const Schema = Mongoose.Schema

    // Field Schema
    const fieldSchema = new Schema({
        name: {
            type: Schema.Types.String
        }
    })

    // Partition Schema
    const partitionSchema = new Schema({
        name: {
            type: Schema.Types.String
        },
        // `fields` is an array of objects that must follow the `fieldSchema`
        fields: [ fieldSchema ]
    })

    return Mongoose.model( 'Partition', partitionSchema )
}
```

Then I have another model (`Asset` model), which has an `attributes` array, which holds objects that each have two items, `_field` and `value`. the `_field` needs to be an ID that will reference an item in the Partition models `fields._id` values.

Heres the Asset model:

```js
// Asset model
module.exports = Mongoose => {     
    const Schema = Mongoose.Schema

    const assetSchema = new Schema({
        attributes: [{
           // The attributes._field should reference one of the Partition field values
            _field: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Partition.fields' // <-- THIS LINE
            },
            value: {
                type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
                required: true
            }
        }],
        // Reference the partition ID this asset belongs to
        _partition: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Partition'
        }
    })

    return Mongoose.model( 'Asset', assetSchema )
}
```

Where I'm running into issues, is with the `_field` item in the `Asset` schema. Im not sure what I should set as the `ref` value, since its referencing a sub-schema (meaning the `Field` schema within the `Partition` schema)

I may have overlooked it in the docs, but I didn't see anything. How can I reference a models sub-schema, so when I [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) that item in the query, it populates it with the sub-documents inside the `Partition` model documents?

Ive tried to reference the field documents as `Partition.fields`, which resulted in the error:

> MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Partition.fields".

I tried the above `ref` value based on what I read from another SO thread, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could you just have your partition contain an array of refs to fields? e.g. fields: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'field' } ]

Comment: I was actually thinking about that... But if I can avoid that, id rather avoid it. If no one can give me an answer on how to do it, then ill have to do that. But I think its possible, at least [from reading this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853383/mongoose-objectid-that-references-a-sub-document), I think im just doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this isn't possible.. So ill just resort to creating another model